# var keyword in try/catch expressions: JSLint bug or global assignment?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

I noticed an interesting result from [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) while researching a [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/collection-of-ajax-methods) question. JSLint complained that a variable was *used before it was defined*. Here is a shortened version of code that produces the same result:

```
(function () {
    try {
        var a = 0;
        throw { name: "fakeError" };
    } catch (e) {
        a = 1;
    }
}());
```

My understanding of JavaScript says that the above code should be equivalent to:

```
(function () {
    var a;
    try {
        a = 0;
        throw { name: "fakeError" };
    } catch (e) {
        a = 1;
    }
}());
```

and indeed, neither example causes `a` to exist in the global scope when run through Firebug. I took a look at section 12.14 of the [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), but I don't see anything that would lead me to think the functions should be treated differently. Is this just a bug in JSLint, or are the two expressions different in some functional way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a bug, but JSLint's default options would prefer it if you moved all your var statements to the top anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While enclosing some block of code in curly braces `{...}` merely doesn't create a new scope in javascript, **`catch` is an exception as noted in [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2)**. *The code inside catch block has a different scope in comparison to the code outside. its treated like functions inner scope.*

In other words, as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Unconditional_catch_clause):

> **The catch block is unique** in that JavaScript creates this identifier when the catch block is entered and it adds it to the current scope; the identifier lasts only for the duration of the catch block; after the catch block finishes executing, the identifier is no longer available.

```
function f() {
  try {
    throw "foo";
  } catch (e) {
  }
  // e undefined here
}
```

And as you know, one cannot expect variable hoisting from 2 different scopes of code in javascript. So, JSLint complains because he/she ;-) knows this.